# Prompt and input numbers and calculate sum, difference, and product

Tags: java

The assignment is to "write a Java program to prompt for and input three numbers. Output the sum of the largest two numbers. Output the difference of the largest and smallest number. Output the product of the smallest two numbers."

I've written the code out but it's not calculating properly. I've included my code below so please feel free to take a look and critique as needed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework4a {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        //Declare Scanner object and three numbers (ints) and ints for smallest and largest numbers
        Scanner keyboard;
        int firstUsernumber;
        int secondUsernumber;
        int thirdUsernumber;
        int largestnumber;
        int smallestnumber;
        int largestnumber2;
        int smallestnumber2;
        int largestnumber3;
        int smallestnumber3;

        //Instantiate keyboard
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt the user for input
        System.out.print("Enter your first number here: ");

        //Obtain and store first number
        firstUsernumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Prompt the user for second input
        System.out.print("Enter your second number here: ");

        //Obtain and store the second input
        secondUsernumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Prompt the user for third input
        System.out.print("Enter your third number here: ");

        //Obtain and store the second input
        thirdUsernumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Determine largest number
        if (firstUsernumber > secondUsernumber) {
            largestnumber = firstUsernumber;
            smallestnumber = secondUsernumber;
        } else {
            largestnumber = secondUsernumber;
            smallestnumber = firstUsernumber;}
        if (secondUsernumber > thirdUsernumber) {
            largestnumber2 = secondUsernumber;
            smallestnumber2 = thirdUsernumber;
        } else {
            largestnumber2 = thirdUsernumber;
            smallestnumber2 = secondUsernumber;}
        if (firstUsernumber > thirdUsernumber) {
            largestnumber3 = firstUsernumber;
            smallestnumber3 = thirdUsernumber;
        } else {
            largestnumber3 = thirdUsernumber;
            smallestnumber3 = firstUsernumber;

        }//Ending bracket of if statement

        //Calculate sum of largest numbers
        System.out.println("The sum of the largest numbers is: " + (largestnumber + largestnumber2));

        //Calculate the difference of the largest and smallest number
        System.out.println("The difference of the largest number and smallest number is: " + (largestnumber - smallestnumber));

        //Calculate the product of the smallest numbers
        System.out.println("The product of the smallest numbers is: " + (smallestnumber*smallestnumber3));

    }//Ending bracket method main

}//Ending bracket class Homework4a
```

Comment: _it's not calculating properly_ does not tell us much. Explain what value(s) you expect and why. Then tell us what values you actually get and why they are wrong.

Comment: If input is `1 5 3`, then you get `largestnumber = 5` and `largestnumber2 = 5`. That doesn't seem right, does it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//this program takes three integers from the user and outputs the sum of the largest two numbers, the difference of the largest and smallest number, and the product of the smallest two numbers.
// done by Nadim Baraky
public class OperationsOnNumbers {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

     //declare three integer variables
     int firstMax, secondMax, min;

     //firstMax: largest number; secondMax: the number in between; min: the smallest number.

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
     int firstNumber = input.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
     int secondNumber = input.nextInt();

     System.out.print("Enter your third number: ");
     int thirdNumber = input.nextInt();

     input.close();


     firstMax = Math.max(Math.max(firstNumber, secondNumber),thirdNumber);

     if(firstMax == firstNumber) {
            secondMax = Math.max(secondNumber, thirdNumber);
     } 

     else if(firstMax == secondNumber) {
            secondMax = Math.max(firstNumber, thirdNumber);
     }

     else {
            secondMax =  Math.max(firstNumber, secondNumber);
     }

     min = Math.min(Math.min(firstNumber, secondNumber), thirdNumber);      

     System.out.println("The sum of the largest two numbers is: " + (firstMax + secondMax));
     System.out.println("The difference of the largest and smallest numbers is: " + (firstMax - min));
     System.out.println("The product of the smallest two numbers: " + secondMax * min);

    }

}
```